# $location.url() is not redirecting but browser url is changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

$locantion.url is not working inside the angular app,  Here is the idea what I am trying,

I have a list of item "/list", I click one of the items to edit, so my route changes to "/edit", inside edit view when I click cancel button to go back to "/list" page, I am facing this problem where it's not redirecting back to list page but browser URL is changing.

```
<a data-ng-click="redirect()" />

$scope.redirect = function() {
  console.log("hello");
  var url = "some url";
   $location.url(url)
}
```

I am able to see "hello" in console terminal.
I have tried following ways to solve the problem but no luck.

```
1- $timeout(function() {
      $location.url(url)
    }, 100);


2-  $timeout(function () {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
         $location.path(url);
       });
   }, 100);
```

**Note**: don't want to use $window.location.href=url, since will reload the whole page.

Comment: Were you even able to access the redirect() function? Can you please verify by adding console.log() inside the function

Comment: I assume that you attached `redirect()` to `$scope` somewhere?  this function would never be called the way you are declaring it in this example...